# facebook like lightbox plugin with comment feature on photo

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

Is there any good plugin for implementing the lightbox with comment feature as in facebook,google+.

I am planning to use it in asp.net mvc 3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is the best Javascript lightbox implementation, hands down.

As for the comment features, [Disqus](http://disqus.com/welcome/) might me your style.

Best of all, these all work on the client-side, so it shouldn't matter whether your backend is in .NET or plain old C!

Answer (score 1):

- I will not give you a lightbox example because many of them are
  really good (colorbox, fancybox ...)
- For facebook comments, take a look at this tutorial :
  http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/facebook-comments-plugin-for-wordpress.html
  and try implementing it in your lightbox, with a `$.append` for
  instance...

Comment: hi what i am looking for is not the comment that gets posted to the facebook wall.I was looking for facebook like feature where user can post comment on photos while navigating.Is there any such plugins available.I have already implemented the lightbox plugin for image navigation but what i need is i should be able to add the comments into the image while  navigating through it.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a lightbox gallery plugin called [lightgallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) where you can include facebook comments. Here is the [demo](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/comment-box.html#lg=2&slide=0)..
I know this is an old question but someone may still be looking for an answer..